# Redirect to route without a query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I redirect to a route without getting a query string on my URL?

Route configuration...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ApplicationStatus",
    url: "join/ApplicationStatus/{applicationKey}/{characterId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Join", action = "ApplicationStatus" }
);
```

Controller code to redirect...

```
    return RedirectToAction("ApplicationStatus", new { 
        applicationKey = applicationKey,
        characterId =_sm.JoinState.CharacterId
    });
```

Controller action method...

```
public ActionResult ApplicationStatus(string applicationKey, long characterId)
{
    return View(new ApplicationStatus());
}
```

So when I am redirected from the controller the browser gives me the following url...

```
http://localhost/TestApp/Join/ApplicationStatus?applicationKey=xxxxxxx&characterId=nnnnnnnn
```

but I would like to get this...

```
http://localhost/TestApp/Join/ApplicationStatus/xxxxxxx/nnnnnnnn
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RedirectToRoute`.

Try this instead.

```
    return RedirectToRoute("ApplicationStatus", new { 
        applicationKey = applicationKey,
        characterId =_sm.JoinState.CharacterId
    });
```